# Want to calculate the sum of the count rendered by group by option

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have a table with the columns such id, tid, companyid, ttype etc..

the id may be same for many companyid but unique within the companyid and
tid is always unique and

i want to calculate the total no of transactions entered in the table,

a single transaction may be inserted in more than one row,

for example,

```
id tid companyid ttype 
1  1   1         xxx
1  2   1         may be null
2  3   1         yyy
2  4   1         may be null
2  5   1         may be null
```

the above entries should be counted as only 2 transactions ..

it may be repeated for many companyids..

so how do i calculate the total no of transactions entered in the table

i tried

```
select sum(count(*)) from transaction group by id,companyId;
```

but doesn't work

```
select count(*) from transaction group by id;
```

wont work because the id may be repeated for different companyids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to rephrase your requirement. But from my understanding, following could work:

```
select count( distinct id, companyid ) from transaction ;
```

Comment: the above query returns 7932 so i think the above value is appropriate. Ill try that with a smaller set of records

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(s.counts) transactions FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) counts FROM transaction GROUP BY id,companyId) s;
```